# как работать с API

Tags: php, api

Как взаимодействовать с `API` посредством `PHP` , есть адрес нужно методом `POST` Отправить на него пустой или с параметрами запрос , который отдаст результат , как вообще и каким средствами это делается ?

Comment: средствами php. Задайте конкретный вопрос!

Comment: @Dmitriy примеры коды что бы отправить POST запрос и получить ответ

Comment: ну POST запрос на php можно отправить 3-мя способами. Через сокет, через curl, или хитро через file_get_content()

Comment: @Dmitriy примеры можно ? и какой способ на ваш взгляд предпочтительнее ?

Comment: если ни разу не отправляли проще всего curl`ом

Comment: @Dmitriy пример можно ?

Answer (score -1):

```
$url = "http://myapi.com";


$post_data = array (
    "foo" => "bar",
    "query" => "Nettuts",
    "action" => "Submit"
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// указываем, что у нас POST запрос
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// добавляем переменные
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

в `$url` адрес вашего API

в `$post_data` параметры массивом (Имя => значение)

в `$output` получите ответ

Comment: Если нужно без параметров post_data отставлять пустой ?
Вида? : $post_data = array (
    "" => "",
    "" => "",
    "" => ""
);

Comment: @user335973 Нет вот эту строку удалить curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); Ну и $post_data не нужен

Comment: @user335973 если получилось, поставьте рядом с ответом галочку